# Использование object

Tags: c#, объекты

Есть метод обработки события

```
private void BillsPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    billsPanel.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
    mouse_offset = new Point(-e.X, -e.Y);
}
```

В дальнейшем мне надо будет использовать тот же метод для другий объектов. Могу ли я как-то использовать `object sender`. Чтобы писать `sender.Cursor` Если да, то каким именно образом?

---

UPD: Возникла новая задача. Надо было методы для передвижения элементов - панелей и формы. С панелями разобрался, а с формой творятся чудеса - она ужасно прыгает помимо того, что стоит if, в котором координаты не отнимаются.

```
private void Panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = sender as Control;
        if (sender is Form)
            obj = sender as Form;
        else if (sender is Control)
            obj = sender as Control;

        if ((sender is Control) && (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left))
        {
            Point mousePos = MousePosition;
            mousePos.Offset(mouse_offset.X - this.Location.X,
                mouse_offset.Y - this.Location.Y);
            obj.Location = mousePos;
        } else if((sender is Form) && (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left))
        {
            Point mousePos = MousePosition;
            mousePos.Offset(mouse_offset.X, mouse_offset.Y); 
            obj.Location = mousePos;
        }
```

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? Я написал Вам пример, где есть проверка типа параметра `sender`. Вы эту проверку проигнорировали и спрашиваете, будет ли все хорошо. Все будет плохо, если `sender` `null` или не `Control`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил. Спасибо большое.)

Comment: Form это Control. Посмотрите иерархию: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void BillsPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (sender is Control)
  {
    Control control = (Control)sender;
    control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
  }
  mouse_offset = new Point(-e.X, -e.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Приведите ваш объект к нужному типу и используйте:

```
var obj = sender as Panel;
```

"Но есть нюанс" функцию можно будет использовать только для объектов этого типа. Поэтому есть смысл подъняться по "дереву предков" до первого имеющего нужное вам свойство или функцию.